# Android Application crash on Android 13

Tags: android, android-layout, crash, layout-inflater, inflate-exception

Getting weird crash in Samsung android 13 devices, but this is working fine in other devices. Recently we are getting one crash in firebase crash analytics, below is the crash report . Application is targeting api level 33 and so far crash reported only in samsung android 13 devices.

**edit_texts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_input1_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_field_text_color"
        android:theme="@style/login_floating_text_style">


        <com.mobileaware.unified.ui.controls.common.MaEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_input1"
            style="@style/input_field_validation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_input2_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_field_text_color"
        android:theme="@style/login_floating_text_style">

    <com.mobileaware.unified.ui.controls.common.MaEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_input2"
            style="@style/input_field_validation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_input3_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_field_text_color"
        android:theme="@style/login_floating_text_style">

    <com.mobileaware.unified.ui.controls.common.MaEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_input3"
            style="@style/input_field_validation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Stack Trace :**

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #21 `com.xyz.abc:layout/edit_texts: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Typeface.getWeight()' on a null object reference

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Typeface.getWeight()' on a null object reference

keyboard_arrow_up
com.google.android.material.resources.TypefaceUtils.maybeCopyWithFontWeightAdjustment (TypefaceUtils.java:57)
com.google.android.material.internal.CollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTypefaceInternal (CollapsingTextHelper.java:480)
com.google.android.material.internal.CollapsingTextHelper.setTypefaces (CollapsingTextHelper.java:463)
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.setEditText (TextInputLayout.java:1426)
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.addView (TextInputLayout.java:836)
android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:5268)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1149)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1106)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1148)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1106)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:692)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:544)
arrow_right
```

com.mobileaware.unified.ui.fragments.NativeLoginFragment.showTabs (NativeLoginFragment.java:364)
com.mobileaware.unified.ui.presenters.NativeLoginFragmentPresenter.bind (NativeLoginFragmentPresenter.java:92)
com.mobileaware.unified.ui.presenters.NativeLoginFragmentPresenter.loadData (NativeLoginFragmentPresenter.java:114)
com.mobileaware.unified.ui.presenters.BasePresenter.loadData (BasePresenter.java:484)
com.mobileaware.unified.ui.fragments.NativeLoginFragment.injectPresenter (NativeLoginFragment.java:673)
com.mobileaware.unified.ui.fragments.BaseFragment.onResume (BaseFragment.java:214)
com.mobileaware.unified.ui.fragments.NativeLoginFragment.onResume (NativeLoginFragment.java:1244)
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume (Fragment.java:3071)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.resume (FragmentStateManager.java:605)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:285)
androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController$FragmentStateManagerOperation.complete (SpecialEffectsController.java:771)

Comment: Post the full stack trace, and your code for your layout/edit_texts

Comment: @GabeSechan added logcat

Comment: So the problem is that it's trying to get the weight of a font that doesn't exist.  Are you setting a font in your styles?  If so, you're doing something wrong there.

Comment: @GabeSechan if its related to font, it should affect all the device, right?. Issue occurring only in samsung device with android 13 OS, others working fine.

Comment: If you're relying on a font that doesn't exist on the device it could be device related.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an issue in implementation of TextInputLayout, as it can call: (TextInputLayout.java:1426)

```
 collapsingTextHelper.setTypefaces(this.editText.getTypeface());
```

with null typeface.

It happened when turning on the Bold text in Android 13:
Settings -> Display size & text -> Bold text

In my case the issue was in the style of com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText.

So try to remove and fix the style of MaEditText in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same nasty crash.

In my case the problem was the following line inside the style:
**@android:style/TextAppearance.Small**

this in combination with Android 13: Settings -> Display size & text -> Bold text leads to the crash even if your device is in debug mode. Remove that line to fix the crash.